# Create Google like document search page

Tags: pdf, solr

Good day,

I have thoroughly searched the internet (and this site) but have not found an (complete) answer and have not yet been able to implement my own solution.
If it seems I missed a solution already posted on Stackoverflow; my apologies in advance.

My company scans all incoming mail.
These are then processed by ABBYY Finereader for OCR data. 
All these documents reside on a NAS in a datacenter and are accessible through a WEBDAV connection. What I want is to index all these files (let's stick with only PDF for now) and make them searchable, and accessible through a Google like search website where a result can be clicked to open the corresponding pdf file in the browser for viewing / downloading.

Here is the problem;
I have setup SOLR / Tika and can index a pdf file, search for it and find the result.
What is the best way to index the entire folder the scanned documents are saved to?
Ideally all this runs on a linux server so I can mount this directory.

How do I watch this directory for new files so that they are automatically indexed?

How do I track files if they are moved to a (new) directory within the Root (or are deleted / renamed) and have the index updated automatically?

What's the preferred way to create the front end for the user? I can customize Solr/browse but I'd rather use Rails to build the site (simply because I'm familiar with it) and would like to send a request with query data to Solr and get a response / array back to present to the user.

Last but not least;
If anyone has a good suggestion for a commercial product that provides this functionality, I'd like to hear it. I have no intention to reinvent the wheel, but my search did not lead me to much.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking too many questions at once. So, you get a bunch of pointers to chase and hopefully it is useful to somebody else as well.

1. You cannot "customize Solr/browse" - Solr is not secure to expose directly to the user application
2. You can use DataImportHandler (DIH) with nested entities using [FileListEntityProcessor](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#FileListEntityProcessor) (with rootEntity=false) to pick up the files and [TikaEntityProcessor](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/TikaEntityProcessor) inside to index a bunch of files. This will not help you however to delete files that have been removed. Maybe you need a stub file or some similar thing for that.
3. [ManifoldCF](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/en_US/index.html#What+Is+Apache+ManifoldCF%3F) uses Solr and it's file system adapter may be smarter than DIH
4. [Lucidworks](http://lucidworks.com/) is a commercial product with Solr inside and probably has file system adapter and large number of other features you could look at
5. [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/) is a commercial product with big data pipeline (which includes document injesting) and uses Solr. Importantly, it also comes pre-configured with [Hue](http://gethue.com/), which may give you at least a version version of the interface.